# Unable to use a defined state variable in the init()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a search bar in my app, as now I want to use the keyword typed in the search bar to make an API call to fetch backend data, here is my code:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @State private var searchText : String=""
    @ObservedObject var results:getSearchList
    init(){

        results = SearchList(idStr: self.searchText)
    }
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                  
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Search"))
            }
            
        }
}
```

I implement `SearchBar` view followed the this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-search-bar/ exactly,
and `getSearchList`  is a class which has an var called idStr,

```
struct searchResEntry: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id:Int
    var comment:String
    
}

class SearchList: ObservableObject {
  // 1.
    @Published var todos = [searchResEntry]()
    var idStr: String
    init(idStr: String) {
        self.idStr = idStr
        let url = URL(string: "https://..." + idStr)!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([searchResEntry].self, from: todoData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.todos = decodedData
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

the problem I am struggling now is that I want to use the variable `searchText` to initialize the `getSearchList` ,  `getSearchList`   has an var called idStr, this idStr is to used to store the typed keyword, my code always get an error: `'self' used before all stored properties are initialized` , I have no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Your base approach is wrong, i can show you a quick fix to silent the xcode errors, but it won't solve your problem. Add `getSearchList` declaration to your question and explain what you want to do so we can help you choose a right/semi-right way for what you want to achieve.

Comment: What you mean my base approach is wrong?

Comment: The way you are initializing the view wont work well. e.g. the view won't get updated after search text is changed.

Comment: I followed  this https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-search-bar/ tutorial to implement the seachbar, and I add a 'Text(searchText)' under the 'SearchBar(text: $searchText)', each time I change the word typed in, the text view below would change as it changes

Comment: If are exactly following that post, then everything should work. Now that not everything works, it means you are doing something differently than the blog post (you are adding the ObservedObject). I asked for more info otherwise i can't make your thing work properly.

Comment: I will update my post right now to add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code, edited by me:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @StateObject var results = SearchList()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $results.searchText)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Search"))
        }
    }
    
}

struct SearchResEntry: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var backdrop_path:String
}

class SearchList: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var todos = [SearchResEntry]()
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $searchText.debounce(
            for: .seconds(0.2),
            scheduler: RunLoop.main
        ).sink { _ in
            self.performSearch()
        }
    }
    
    func performSearch() {
        if let pathParam = searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed),
           let url = URL(string: "https://hw9node-310902.uc.r.appspot.com/mutisearch/\(pathParam)") {
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let todoData = data {
                        
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([SearchResEntry].self, from: todoData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.todos = decodedData
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No data")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }.resume()
        } else {
            print("Invalid URL")
        }
    }
    
}
```

#### Explanation

You are free to reverse the optional changes i made, but here are my explanations:

- Use capital letter at the beginning of a Type's name. e.g write `struct SearchResEntry`, don't write `struct searchResEntry`. This is convention. Nothing big will happen if you don't follow conventions, but if anyone other than you (or maybe even you in 6 months) look at that code, chances are they go dizzy.
- Dont start a Type's name with verbs like `get`! Again, this is just a convention. If anyone sees a `getSomething()` or even `GetSomething()` they'll think thats a function, not a Type.
- Let the searchText be a published property in your model that performs the search. Don't perform search on init, instead use a function so you can initilize once and perform search any time you want (do `results.performSearch()` in your View). Also you can still turn your `searchText` into a binding to pass to your search bar (look at how i did it).

#### EDIT answer to your comment

I could right-away think of 3 different answers to your comment. This is the best of them, but also the most complicated one. Hopefully i chose the right option:

As you can see in the `class SearchList` i've added 2 things. First one is a cancellable to store an `AnyCancellable`, and second is the thing in `init() { ... }`. In init, we are doing something which results in an `AnyCancellable` and then we are storing that in the variable that i added.

What am i doing In `init`?
first `$searchText` gives us a `Publisher`. Basically, the publisher is called whenever the `searchText` value changes. Then you see `.debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), on: RunLoop.main)` which means only let the latest input go through and reach the next thing (the next thing is `.sink { }` as you can see), only if the user has stopped writing for `0.2 seconds`. This is very helpful to avoid a load of requests to the server which can eventually make servers give you a `429 Too Many Requests` error if many people are using your app (You can remove the whole `.debounce` thing if you don't like it). And the last thing is `.sink { }` which when any value reaches that point, it'll call the `performSearch` func for you and new results will be acquired from the server.

#### Alternative way

(again talking about your comment)
This is the simpler way. Do as follows:

- remove `init() { ... }` completely if you've added it
- remove `var cancellable` completely if you've added it
- in your SearchView, do:

```
.onChange(of: results.searchText) { _ in
      results.performSearch()
}
```

pretty self-explanatory; it'll perform the search anytime the `searchText` value is changed.

Comment: I am trying to understand your code. This search function need to display the list of results in realtime, e.g. I entered "game", then it displays the list of results fetched from https://hw9node-310902.uc.r.appspot.com/mutisearch/game automatically, if then I delete the last character 'e', it would automatically display the list of results from https://hw9node-310902.uc.r.appspot.com/mutisearch/gam, so I am confused where to put results.performSearch()

Comment: Hope this updated answer answers your question.

Comment: it works! Really appreciate your patience in answering my question.